# how to fix "cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method." - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interface, dagger

whenever i try to run the application i am facing this error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] api.PrayerTimesInterface cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

and this is the interface:

```
    @GET("calendar")
suspend fun getPrayerTimes(
    @Query("latitude") latitude: Double,
    @Query("longitude") longitude: Double,
    @Query("method") method: Int,
    @Query("month") month: Int,
    @Query("year") year: Int,
): Response<PlayerTime>

@GET("calendarByAddress")
suspend fun getPrayerAddress(
    @Query("address") address: String,
    @Query("method") method: Int,
    @Query("month") month: Int,
    @Query("year") year: Int,
): Response<PlayerTime>
}
```

i tried to add "@Provides" but still facing the same error.
the same code available in different version of the app and it's working fine.

i tried the solution here:
[How to fix "cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method" error in dagger2 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536783/how-to-fix-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method-error-in-d)

but it didn't work for me

did i do anything wrong here?

Comment: You need to add a provider method for `PrayerTimesInterface` in your network module or whichever module you are using for it .https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface classes cannot be directly injected as they do not have constructors. I suppose you are using the `PrayerTimesInterface` with `Retrofit`. So inject `PrayerTimesInterface` with `Retrofit`'s `create` method.

In `module` class

```
@Provides
internal fun providesPrayerTimes(): PrayerTimesInterface {
        return Retrofit.Builder().build().create(PrayerTimesInterface::class.java)
    }
```

You can also create Retrofit injection with all the options required and take it in `providesPrayerTimes` method to create `PrayerTimesInterface`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, now its working

Comment: is it possible to help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820655/how-to-open-link-from-api-in-fragment-kotlin-retrofit

Answer (score 0):

For some one it may help.

```
Make sure you bind your implementation and interface in module kotlin file.

in the kotlin file which marked with @module annotation, would be having all bindings. 
In these bindings you need to mention the newly created interface and its implementation.
```